# PHP - After user login, redirect to address stored on database

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication

I am building a simple web app. After logging in it should redirect users to a specific map page that they can then edit. The address of each map is stored in a simple database along with the user names and passwords.

Below is the code I have for log in (the login form being on an index.php page)

I am having trouble getting the redirect to work, with "site" being the row name where the address is stored.

```
include 'db_connect.php';
    include 'functions.php';
    sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a php session. 

    if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) { 
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.
       if(login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
          // Login success and shoud redirect to 'site'
        header("Location: '$site");
        } else {
      // Login failed
     header("Location: '..\..\..\?error=1");

   }
} else { 
   // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page.
   echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

Comment: Why there is a `'` in `header("Location: '$site");`?

Comment: Can you include a sample values that is stored as `$site`? Also, you may want to remove the apostrophe `'` before the `$site`

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because as far as I can see the header redirect wont work due to a ' before the $site. Try removing that. There is also one in the following header for the error redirect. Try:    header("Location: ".$site); instead.

Comment: And add exit(0); after header();

Comment: As the answer from @Sami Dz Hamida says... $site is not declared, I'm asuming this is pseudocode, or did you really forget to declare it? xD

Comment: I've removed the `'` and it still returns a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$site` hasn't been declared, meaning it has no value.

So give `$site` a value and it will work.

Comment: I assumed it would be returned from the DB as that was being queried for the login. How do I include `$site`so I can deliver the information?

Comment: It can be returned from the DB, but just set it.

Answer (score 2):

in the login success:

```
header("Location: '$site");
------------------^
```

that single quote ? remove it.

on login failed:

```
 header("Location: '..\..\..\?error=1");
 ------------------^
```

remove that single quote as well (Thx @Petr R.) and use an absolute path instead, maybe the path is wrong. use something like `http://mysite.com/index.php?error=1`

---

Also be more specific with your errors, I'm having troubles with the redirect is way too generalized, does it show a blank page? don't load? shows any error?

use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

to display your errors if you are on production environment.

Comment: There is also an extra `'` in `header("Location: '..\..\..\?error=1");`

Comment: I added error reporting and got this:
"Notice: Undefined variable: site in /home/ffhpro5/public_html/map/login3/secure/process_login.php on line 15"
Which is the line with `header("Location: $site");`so I see that Sami Dz Hamida is correct. 
Now I need to understand how to pull that information from the DB

Comment: Yes, then look how to pull data from the database, I suggest you learning to use PDO, but take out the single quotes mentioned as well, they will make your code fail anyway

Comment: Single quotes removed and googling commencing